# Displacement around the x axis, how to change a function location

Tags: fitting

While plotting a function I want to change the location of x.
I am doing a regression with the logistic function

```
n = 3998000
modelo = w/(1 + ((w - n)/n)*E^(-q*t))
fit = FindFit[l, modelo, {{w, 9000000}, q}, t]
Show[Plot[modelo /. fit, {t, 0, 2015}], ListPlot[l]]
```

- $n$ is the initial population
- $w$ is the capacity of my logistic function
- $q$ is the coefficient rate
- $l$ is my data

> l={{1965.,18.5592},{1966.,19.109},{1967.,19.6698},{1968.,20.2349},{1969.,20.7953},{1970.,21.3448},{1971., 21.8802},{1972.,22.4043},{1973.,22.9248},{1974.,23.4527},{1975.,23.9962},{1976.,24.5576},{1977., 25.1346},{1978.,25.7253},{1979.,26.3262},{1980.,26.9346},{1981.,27.5502},{1982.,28.1735},{1983., 28.8033},{1984.,29.438},{1985.,30.0765},{1986.,30.7181},{1987.,31.3625},{1988.,32.009},{1989.,
>   32.6573},{1990.,33.3069},{1991.,33.9573},{1992.,34.6082},{1993.,35.2605},{1994.,35.9154},{1995., 36.5739},{1996.,37.2361},{1997.,37.9014},{1998.,38.5681},{1999.,39.2341},{2000.,39.898},{2001.,
>   40.5586},{2002.,41.2163},{2003.,41.8721},{2004.,42.5276},{2005.,43.184},{2006.,43.8414},{2007.,
>   44.4984},{2008.,45.153},{2009.,45.8026},{2010.,46.4448},{2011.,47.0788},{2012.,47.7044}}.......

The plot is working fine but is taking $t$ as going from 0 to 115 instead of 1900 to 2015. How can I take the function from region [0, 115] to the region [1900, 2015]? I hope I am getting better at asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

Both plots are differently scaled, so I propose to use `Overlay` with two Y-axes

```
list =
     {{1965., 18.5592}, {1966., 19.109}, {1967., 19.6698}, {1968., 
       20.2349}, {1969., 20.7953}, {1970., 21.3448}, {1971., 
       21.8802}, {1972., 22.4043}, {1973., 22.9248}, {1974., 
       23.4527}, {1975., 23.9962}, {1976., 24.5576}, {1977., 
       25.1346}, {1978., 25.7253}, {1979., 26.3262}, {1980., 
       26.9346}, {1981., 27.5502}, {1982., 28.1735}, {1983., 
       28.8033}, {1984., 29.438}, {1985., 30.0765}, {1986., 
       30.7181}, {1987., 31.3625}, {1988., 32.009}};

n = 3998000;
modelo = w/(1 + ((w - n)/n)*E^(-q*t));
fit = FindFit[list, modelo, {{w, 9000000}, q}, t];

C1 = RGBColor[0.368, 0.507, 0.710];
C2 = RGBColor[0.881, 0.611, 0.142];

p1 =
  ListLinePlot[
   list,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameLabel -> "Population",
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, C1, Automatic, Automatic},
   FrameTicks -> {All, All, None, None},
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{1965, Automatic}, All},
   PlotStyle -> C1];

p2 =
  Plot[
   modelo /. fit, {t, 0, 1},
   Axes -> False,
   ImagePadding -> 45,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
   FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, "Model fit"},
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, C2},
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All},
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   PlotStyle -> C2];

Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]